# CSS: How can I get 2 elements to float at the bottom

Tags: css

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#left, #right {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: inline-block;
}

#right {
    float: right;
}

<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        left
    </div>
    <div id="right">right <br />right <br />right <br />right <br />right <br />right <br />right <br /></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nxtbqqps/

I need to have one span float left and the other span float right, both aligned to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `Flexbox`, you just have to set

1. `justify-content: space-between` to position elements left and right
2. `align-items: flex-end` to position elements at bottom of parent.

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div id="right">right
    <br />right
    <br />right
    <br />right
    <br />right
    <br />right
    <br />right
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #left, #right {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
    }

   #left {
        left: 0
        }

    #right {
        right: 0;

    }
```

you can use `position:fixed` for this or `position: absolute` based on your requirement

Comment: Be aware that `position: fixed` will affix the items to the bottom of the window and not to the bottom of the nearest containing element with a non-static position (or the body, whichever comes first).

Comment: yes you are  correct thanks .. question said bottom and i thought bottom of viewport .

Comment: Sorry I mean bottom of the container

Comment: oh i see , you can give your container `position:relative` and `position:absolute` to components to aligned left and right